# How to rename MSMQ queue

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, msmq

I need to rename MSMQ queue from Powershell.

Here is what I'm running:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$privateQueues = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".") 

foreach ($queue in $privateQueues) 
{
    if($queue.QueueName.Contains("foo"))
    {
        $queue.QueueName = "bar"

         Write-Host $queue.QueueName
    }
}
```

Write-Host prints a new name, but when browsing a queue list via "Computer Management", it is not changed.

**Update:** Based on this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/230709/can-a-private-msmq-queue-be-renamed), it cannot be renamed. The solution is to delete and re-add.

Answer (score 0):

What you are fetching are private queue's and thus should be prefixed with `Private$`. try setting it like

```
$queue.QueueName = "localhost\Private$\bar";
```

(OR)

```
$queue.QueueName = ".\Private$\bar";
```

See [`MessageQueue.QueueName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.queuename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that as well; getting: "Path syntax is invalid."